# Why does textcomp not load the glyph from my font but replaces it?

Tags: font-encodings, textcomp

I converted a font some time ago and now there is an update to this font. As the new font files are provided by a different company, there are slight differences, especially with symbols. However I figured out all differences in the glyph positions and set them up accordingly in a modified encoding file. There is a problem however: When I try to access the symbols, e.g. through `\textuparrow` PDFtex tells me:

```
Package textcomp Info: Symbol \textuparrow not provided by
(textcomp)             font family MYFONT-TLF in TS1 encoding.
(textcomp)             Default family used instead on input line 525.
```

But when I put a simple

```
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textuparrow}{TS1}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textuparrow}{TS1}{94}
```

in the preamble, PDFtex does not complain anymore.

What am I doing wrong here, what sort of misconception do I have and what can I change to make this work without adding the above code to my MYFONT.sty file as manual definitions? I checked `textcomp.sty` which has this strange `\tc@check@symbol2` in front, is this maybe my issue:

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textuparrow}%
    {\tc@check@symbol2\textuparrow}
```

As `ts1enc.def` just goes straight with:

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textuparrow}{TS1}{94}
```

Comment: `texdoc ltnews`  ltnews36 section **Encoding subsets for TS1 encoded fonts**

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, I followed this article down to https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf and added ```\DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{MYFONT-*}{1}``` to my font files.

Comment: ah I got pulled away and just came back to check what number you needed:-) can you post a self-answer, thanks

Comment: No problem @DavidCarlisle, I answered myself, please feel free to add what might be useful. One more question: My font has many of the characters that make level 1 sensible, but not all, is there harm in defining it that way anyway?

Comment: no real harm (and easier than defining a new subset), just means latex will not give any high level errors or substitutions, it will simply use the character and get a low level missing character warning or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/ltnews36.pdf referencing to https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf since 2021/06/01 one must declare which subset of glyphs is contained in a TS1 encoded font.
So based on the respective subset, one can select e.g. `\DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{MYFONT-*}{1}` or any other number as appropriate.